# What command should I use to find the file with the maximum size in a certain folder

Tags: linux, windows

What command should I use to find the file with the maximum size in a certain folder containing sub-directories which are several level deep. (in windows / linux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following command under Linux:

```
find /path/to/folder -printf "%p:%k\n" | sort -k 2 -rn -t : | head -n 1 | cut -f 1 -d :
```

If you want to get size also (in kilobytes), you can remove the last `cut`.

Comment: `$ find /path/to/folder -type f -printf "%s %p\n" | sort -n | tail -1`

Answer (score 1):

```
find /dirname -type f -ls | sort -nr -k 7,7 | head -n 1
```

will list all files under dirname and sort them in reverse order (largest first) with a numerical sort for the 7th field.

BTW: This is on Linux/Unix.